# Why does the second code segment run so much faster than the first?

Tags: python

I have two different takes on the same function:

```
def is_prime(number):
    for denominator in range(2, number):
        if denominator ** 2 > number:
            return True
        if number % denominator == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

And

```
def is_prime(number):
    denominator = 2
    while denominator ** 2 <= number:
        if number % denominator == 0:
            return False
        denominator += 1
    return True
```

The first block of code, when used to test the first 10**5 numbers takes ~30 seconds to complete, the second takes around 350ms. Both come to the same answer for all test cases.
Why is there such a large difference in performance?

*Note: This quirk fell out of testing performance of a ctypes import, I am aware that range(math.sqrt(number)) is faster, and that we can use Fermat's little theorem to make it faster still.*

Comment: tentatively the first version has more instructions to run ina  single loop. Whikle the 2nd version has less insrtuctions. For example there are more if and control statements in 1st version. Also it is commonly the case while loops are faster than for loops

Comment: Are you using python2? If so, the range function is creating the whole list first. Try using xrange instead.

Comment: To bolster the comment by @NikosM.: `python -m timeit -s 'i=0' 'for x in range(1000): i+=1' 10000 loops, best of 3: 46.4 usec per loop` versus while: `python -m timeit -s 'i=0' 'while i<1000: i+=1' 10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0299 usec per loop`. This is using python3's `range`

Comment: I'm timing `[is_prime(x) for x in range(100000)]` for both implementations in Python 3, and getting the virtually the same result (1.01sec vs 1.03sec) for each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it's true that snippet 1 has more instructions to execute, two `if` statements will only double your execution time for those if statements (I'm using *only* as a relative term here). The majority of your speed is lost in the `for` loop:

```py
python -m timeit -s 'i=0' 'for x in range(1000): i+=1' 
10000 loops, best of 3: 46.4 usec per loop

python -m timeit -s 'i=0' 'while i<1000: i+=1' 
10000 loops, best of 3: 0.0299 usec per loop
```

You are losing multiple orders of magnitude in the `for` loop, so the `if` statement is relatively inconsequential:

```py
python -m timeit -s 'x=1; y=4' 'x<y'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0256 usec per loop
```

However, I will point out that this is the case for python3's `range` and python2's `xrange`. If you are using python2's `range`, as @jdowner pointed out, you will be generating the entire list of numbers ahead of time